# Upgrading Win 8 to Win 10 not possible

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, motherboard, raid, sata

The screenshot explains everything:
A couple of days ago received a machine with Ryzen 1700 cpu and ASUS X370-Pro motherboard with enabled RAID1 on first 2 SATA ports (in fact on all ports, ask ASUS about that) that has Windows 8.1 x64 on it which cannot be upgraded to original Windows 10 Pro even when the RAID driver is in fact almost the latest at the time of writing this post

Driver versions taken from `Device Manager`:

- AMD RAID Array1 SCSI Disk Device - 6.3.9600.18758
- AMD-RAID Bottom Device - 8.1.0.26 (present 2 times in the manager)
- AMD-Controller [storport] - 8.1.0.26 (present 2 times in the manager)
- AMD-RAID Config Device - 8.1.0.26

`RAIDXpert2` version:

- GUI Version: 9.2.0-00105
- AMD RAIDXpert2 Driver Version: 8.1.0-00026
- AMD RAIDXpert2 Driver Version(Bottom): 8.1.0-00026

Any ideas how to fix this?
[image]

Edit: Slipstreaming the drivers into the Win 10 USB didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@harrymc pointed some good things, sadly it's over. The only way to fix this is to clone the current Win 8 installation to another drive, connect it to USB (stupid motherboard design doesn't allow SATA mode for unused ports when RAID is enabled, all are RAIDed), boot from it and install Win 10 then install the drivers, clone it again on the RAID1 drives and then you can boot from. Pretty awesome AMD and ASUS, pretty awesome

Answer (score 1):

From the AMD Support article
[Unable to proceed with installation or upgrade of Windows® 10 May 2019 Update with SATA or NVMe RAID on AMD Ryzen™ systems](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/pa-260):

> **Issue Description**
>
> Windows 10 May 2019 Update (version 1903) contains new Device
> Input/Output Control (IOCTL) requirements for certain categories of
> device driver. If a user attempts a clean install of Windows 10 May
> 2019 Update using device drivers that do not meet the new
> requirements, the PC may fail to reach the Windows desktop
> environment. If a user attempts a Windows Update upgrade from Windows
> 10 October 2018 Update (version 1809) to Windows 10 May 2019 Update,
> the update will be blocked until updated RAID drivers are installed.
>
> **Solution**
>
> If the user is attempting to update from Windows 10 October 2018
> Update to Windows 10 May 2019 Update, the user must install May 2019
> Update-ready RAID drivers before initiating the upgrade.
>
> If the user is attempting to perform a clean install of Windows 10 May
> 2019 Update, the user must prepare a removable storage device
> containing May 2019 Update-ready RAID drivers.
>
> **Required Drivers**
>
> Users will need to download and install [AMD RAID Installer (SATA,
> NVMe
> RAID)](https://www.amd.com/en/support/chipsets/amd-socket-tr4/x399))
> driver 9.2.0.105 or later.

Download and install the linked drivers before attempting the
installation of Windows 10. Before installing the drivers,
create in Windows 8 a System Restore point to be able to rollback.
Create also a recovery boot media for Windows 8, in case this
installation renders Windows 8 unbootable.

Comment: I am confused by this answer, it appears to only be applicable to Windows 10, not a Windows 8.1 system trying to be upgraded to Windows 10

Comment: @Ramhound: I think the poster needs this driver, since the symptoms match his problem with booting with an earlier driver. Windows 8.1 is certainly "earlier".

Comment: It's not possible to install this version, Win 8.1 reports `The best driver software for your device is already installed`. This is only for Win 10 already in use, probably there isn't a driver that fixes this bug (or at least I didn't find)

Comment: @1000Gbps: You will need to slipstream this driver into the Windows 10 installation media.

Comment: There's lots of information about slipstreaming to be found, for example [this one](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/slipstream-windows-10-integrate-updates-setup-media-iso/) (found via google) or [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-and-remove-drivers-to-an-offline-windows-image?view=windows-11).

Comment: Yep, I forgot about NLite :|

Comment: Mmmm, I accepted the answer but slipstreaming the drivers didn't work (NTLite used and steps from the link reproduced 1:1)

Comment: Have you had the same exact error?

Comment: Yeah, the same error. It's original Win 10 USB from the MS site. This problem won't show in old Intel X79 platform tho

Comment: You might require more drivers from [here](https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/prime/prime-x370-pro/helpdesk_download/?model2Name=PRIME-X370-PRO), or perhaps a BIOS update (to be done carefully).

Comment: Sadly Asus do not offer specific drivers or software, they are the same like those in AMD site :\

Comment: Have you tried upgrading Windows 8.1, or a clean install?

Comment: Clean install is not an option due to too many programs with specific configurations, otoh upgrading is not available in the sense of auto-update feature.

Comment: I would suggest to update the BIOS using the BIOS-Utilities, and also the drivers where the important ones are Chipset, SATA and USB. Slipstream the Windows 10 versions if they are unacceptable to Windows 8.1. What are in the BIOS the options of CSM and Secure Boot?

Comment: BIOS is the latest stable 6042, sadly I found something in AMD forums about compatibility of those chipsets with Win 10. It looks like there's no driver that fixes this problem with Windows 10 1903 and above (May 2019), so the only way is to find pre-May-2019 Windows and install it, because they had no intentions to create driver fix for Win 8/Win 10 RAID-based installations ... Jesus, good job ASUS and AMD, very very good job indeed

Comment: You may get an ISO for previous Windows versions from [Tech Bench](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php), to test this.